# how can really show ProgressDialog while waiting for end process

Tags: java, android, show, progressdialog

I want to show ProgressDialog but ProgressDialog never really rendered !
And I want to end this process to start next state.
this is my code:

```
ProgressDialog waitProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            waitProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            waitProgressDialog.setMessage("please wait..");
            waitProgressDialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {

                @Override
                public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    ExirDebugger.println("----------TEST999999 START");
///same sqlit datasouce select
                    ExirDebugger.println("----------TEST999999 END");
                }
            });
            waitProgressDialog.show();
```

android not render anything while all work end!
can anyone help me?

Comment: and you call at where?

Comment: `AppViewer.getInstance().getActivePortlet()` what does this return?

Comment: waitProgressDialog.dismiss(); <- you use this?

Comment: tank you getActivePortlet() returned last opened activity. I need to dismiss dialog after datasource select end.

Comment: I called it in button click.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(className.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);

 //Do stuff

dialog.dismiss();
```