# Is there Background worker in android? I used AsyncTask suggested in this topic but my progress dialog not show

Tags: android, backgroundworker

Is there any background worker in android!
I used progress dialog in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851343/how-can-really-show-progressdialog-while-waiting-for-end-process)

but no resolve for this suggested.
I need to show a wait dialog and after my process end, do other process.

I used AsyncTask suggested in this topic but my progress dialog not show immediately yet !!

Comment: use asynctask along with progressdialog. search on google on so you will find many related posts.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>    {
        Context context;
        myAsyncTask(Context context)    {
             this.context=context;           
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //Do stuff that you want after completion of background task and also dismiss progress here.
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //create and show progress dialog here
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void… arg0) {
            //background task here
            return null;
        }   
    }
```

and execute like this:

```
myAsyncTask myWebFetch = new myAsyncTask();
                myWebFetch.execute();
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: I need to use progress dialog but my progress dialog show after all task end.rendered this is my code :  DBAsyncTask dba = new DBAsyncTask(this, xmlCommand);
  dba.inProcess = true;
  dba.execute("");
  while (dba.inProcess) {
   try {
    Thread.sleep(200);
    ExirDebugger.println("wwwwait");
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

  }
i started progress dialog in onPreExecute but render progress after work ended!!!!

Comment: why are you using thread.sleep()?? don't use that and put dialog.show in OnpreExecute method of asynctask.