# AsyncTask not show progress dialog immediate

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I used suggestion in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851343/how-can-really-show-progressdialog-while-waiting-for-end-process) but I have same problem yet.
Thanks my friend for suggestion for using AsyncTask but it is not worked for me.
What?
This is my code :

```
DBAsyncTask dba = new DBAsyncTask(this, xmlCommand);
    dba.inProcess = true;
    dba.execute("");
    while (dba.inProcess) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
            println("wwwwait");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public class DBAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    public boolean inProcess;

    public DBAsyncTask(ExirCommandRunner commandRunner,XmlNode xmlCommand) {
        this.commandRunner = commandRunner;
        this.xmlCommand = xmlCommand;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ExirDebugger.println("onPostExecute");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        showProgress();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    ///my process here 
        closeProgress();
        return null;
    }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: close progress should be in onPostExecute.

Comment: no my process is before close it

Comment: @ArmaanStranger why would it be that.  As soon as doInBackground finishes its execution, onPostExecute is automatically called.

Comment: @ObieMD5 yes it is automatically called. so that closing dialog should be in that method.

Comment: @alishekari you should dismiss dialog in PostExecute Method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Thread.sleep()` blocks the UI thread and therefore the progress dialog cannot run. Remove that and the `inProcess` polling mechanism. Also, there's a lot of [references](https://www.google.com/search?q=asynctask%20progressdialog) on using async task with progress dialog.

Comment: thank you! but i need to wait and sleep procedure. my process is complexity and I do not set next state in onPostExecute. i am seeking for solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I explained a detailed usage of ProgressDialog in AsyncTask and the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17527979/1943671

Answer (score 1):

It should be like:

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
             pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activityContext);
             pDialog.setCancelable(false);
             pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait..");
             pDialog.show();
        }
```

and

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) 
        {
            if(pDialog.isShowing())
            {
                pDialog.cancel();
            }
                }
```